# Arc through three points in Asymptote

Tags: asymptote, arc

How to draw the arc through three points (i.e. arc `\widehat{BAC}`) in Asymptote?

I can draw the circumcircle of a triangle using
`import olympiad; draw(circumcircle(A,B,C));` but I don't know how to draw only a portion between B and C that contains A in Asymptote.

Comment: If you know how to do it with a rule and a compass, you would know how to do it in Asymptote. What did you try already?

Comment: Thank you very much for the link!

Comment: I don't think the above link answer the OP's question. I vote to reopen it. Here is a code for a possible answer  `unitsize(1cm);
pair A=(0,0), B=(5,-1), C=(1,4);
pair M=relpoint(A--B,.5), N=relpoint(A--C,.5);
pair Ab=rotate(90,M)*A;
pair Ac=rotate(90,N)*A;
pair O=extension(Ab,M,Ac,N);
draw(A--B--C--cycle,gray);
draw(arc(O,B,C,CW),magenta);

label("$A$",align=W,A);
label("$B$",align=E,B);
label("$C$",align=plain.N,C);`